# Hibernate 3.6 dynamic dialect resolver

Tags: spring, hibernate, configuration

I'm using Spring 4.3 and Hibernate 3.6. I tried specifying a custom Hibernate dialect resolver, but it's not being used.

I put log statements in my custom dialect resolver, but they are never printed.

My specific questions are:

1. How do I get Hibernate 3.6 to pick up my custom dialect resolver?
2. Why is one specific hibernate property (hibernate.dialect_resolvers) being ignored? What is the correct way to set it?

Here are a list of things I tried, and I'm currently out of ideas.

1. I tried setting the dialect_resolvers property on the session factory's hibernate properties

   ```
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <value>
           hibernate.dialect_resolvers=mypackage.MyDialectResolver
           ...
         </value>
   </property>
   ```
2. I tried using a custom SessionFactory bean which extends hibernate3's LocalSessionFactoryBean, and overrode the postProcessConfiguration method to set the Environment.DIALECT_RESOLVERS property. 
   `config.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT_RESOLVER, MyDialectResolver.class.getName());`

   Other properties I'm setting in the session factory work as expected, but are also showing up as nulls when I'm trying to print them. For example, I'm setting a connection provider which works as expected, but is null when accessed via `Environment.getProperties().getProperty(CONNECTION_PROVIDER)`.
   `config.setProperty(Environment.CONNECTION_PROVIDER, CustomConnectionProvider.class.getName());`

   However, when I try to print the dialect resolver property later (inside application code), it does not appear to be set.
   `log.info("Dialect resolver property: " + Environment.getProperties().getProperty(Environment.DIALECT_RESOLVERS));`

   Log output:
   `"Dialect resolver property: null"`
3. I checked the Hibernate source code, and tried setting a system (env) property as well, because those appear to be read during [Environment initialization](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/3.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/Environment.java#L640). And the Environment properties are used to obtain the DIALECT_RESOLVERS setting in [DialectFactory](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/3.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/resolver/DialectFactory.java#L57). But that did not work either.
   `hibernate.dialect_resolvers=mypackage.MyDialectResolver;`

FINAL EDIT:
I added a hibernate.properties, and set the property in it. That worked!
The hibernate.properties file has to be at the root of the classpath, and cannot be nested somewhere deep down. This is because of the way the [Hibernate Environment loads the file](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/3.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/Environment.java#L618)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a hibernate.properties, and set the property in it. That worked!

The hibernate.properties file has to be at the root of the classpath, and cannot be nested somewhere deep down. This is because of the way the [Hibernate Environment loads the file](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/3.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/Environment.java#L618)